# Are the two sentences same meaning?

Tags: meaning

Is the sentence "I didn't marry you because you were rich." same as " I married you not because you were rich but for another reason."

Comment: The first one is ambiguous (although it can always be resolved by context). It *could* mean the same as the second, but it could also mean *"the reason I didn't marry you is that you were rich"*.

Comment: Why does this question remind me of a cellphone? Maybe because yesterday, [this question](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/33476/interpretations-of-she-did-not-buy-the-cell-phone-because-her-sister-had-one) was asked on our sister-site, [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com) :)

Answer (score 0):

They both express the same idea -- that a reason other than wealth is why the speaker married the subject. The first sentence is more likely to be ambiguous, as Peter Shor noted:

- is the speaker married to the subject, for a reason other than wealth?
- is the speaker *not* married to the subject, because they're rich?

In either case, a native speaker would probably expect to hear a *parallel structure* for each sentence. For example:

> I didn't marry you because you were rich. [I married you because you were my soulmate.]

and:

> I married you not because you were rich, [but because you were my soulmate].

Without the parallel construction, the first sentence sounds a little more natural.

Comment: See Peter Shor comment above

Comment: Yes, I saw it. His answer is helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps "I didn't marry you because you were rich." was intended to mean " I married you not because you were rich but for another reason."

However, it could also be interpreted as meaning "I declined to marry you, because I didn't want a rich wife."